# $\partial M\subset M$ implies (Is $(x_n)\subseteq M$ such that $x_n\to x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n \Rightarrow x_0\in M$)

Tags: general-topology

Let $M\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. I want to how to proof:

Why implies 1. $\partial M\subset M$ this type of closedness: 2. Is $(x_n)\subseteq M$ such that $x_n\to x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n \Rightarrow x_0\in M$?

The first conditions sais: Every point x such that $\forall \epsilon >0$ it is $U_\epsilon(x)\cap M\not= \emptyset$ and $U_\epsilon(x)\cap (\mathbb{R}^n\setminus M)\not= \emptyset$, is in M.

Maybe the strategy is to assume that $x_0\notin M$. I started with:For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $U_{\epsilon_n}(x_n)\cap M\not= \emptyset$ and $U_{\epsilon_n}(x_n)\cap (\mathbb{R}^n\setminus M)\not= \emptyset$. But what can I do next, how can I prove it?

I think it is $x_0\in U_{\epsilon_n}(x_n)\cap (\mathbb{R}^n\setminus M)$ for $n\ge N$ for a natural number N, is it correct? How to continue?

Comment: The first condition says - more useful here - "$M$ is closed".

Comment: ok, thank you. But I have to use the definition of boundary points:/.

Answer (score 1):

If $x_n \in M$, and $x_n \to x$, since every $x_n$ is in $M$, every ball around $x$ contains an element of $M$. Then there are two cases:

1. Every ball around $x$ contains an element outside $M$. In this case every ball around $x$ contains an element in $M$ and and element outside $M$, so $x \in \partial M \subseteq M$.
2. There is some ball $B(x,r)$ around $x$ that does not contain any elements outside $M$, in particular $x \in M$ since $x \in B(x,r)$. (This actually shows $x \in M^\circ$, a slightly stronger statement.)

In either case, $x \in M$.

Note that the "better" way to prove this is that $\partial M \subseteq M$ tells you that $M$ is closed, so convergent sequences in $M$ converge to elements of $M$ (A fact you will likely learn later).

Comment: thank you very much, this is very helpful! I understand it.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, don't forget to upvote and/or accept it.